# gnuplot: change x-axis to start from specific numer

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file named 'data.txt':

```
 25
 76
 90
100
120
135
```

And I want to make my plot x-axis looks like this:

```
 0     4     8     12     16     20     24
```

I want to put first value from file to the plot on 4 position then next value to 8 position and so on. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

similar questions have been asked here already, however, I can't recall what the titles were...
In gnuplot, check `help pseudocolumns`. `$0` gives you the line number of the datafile, starting from 0. So, just multiply this with 4 and you'll have your added x-values.

```
plot "data.txt" u ($0*4):1 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red"
```

*Result:*

[image]